# Разрядности при публиковании

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

Как это понимать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е можно собирать с конфигурацией Any CPU и указать в Target runtime конкретную разрядность.

Как оно в итоге соберется, как Any или под конкретный процессор?

Как собрать реальный ANY CPU?

Comment: @rdorn сделайте ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/deploying/), хоть и довольно скромная.

Есть два режима публикации:

- Framework Dependent, в этом режиме можно выбрать целевую среду (Target Runtime) Portable, для которой сборка происходит максимально универсально, с учетом настроек проекта разумеется, именно он вам и нужен. Если же выбрать конкретную платформу и разрядность, то проект собирается под данную платформу и разрядность.
- Self-Contained, в этом режиме сборка всегда происходит под указанную платформу и разрядность. Кроме того, в пакет приложения включаются все необходимые системные библиотеки целевой платформы и среды выполнения .net core с целью исключить необходимость установки дополнительного ПО на целевой машине, правда пакет получается ощутимо толще.