# Собрать консольное приложение как exe

Tags: c#, .net-core

Всем привет!
Создал консольный проект C#, но после сборки в папке bin/debug лежит папка netcoreapp2.1. Есть возможность собрать проект как exe?
[image: Свойства проекта]

Comment: Раз уж вам нужен exe, то используйте .NET Framework вместо .NET Core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не нашел подтверждение тому, что это дубликат, поэтому все таки напишу решение, применимое в Visual Studio для net core начиная с версии 2.0 по текущую 3.1. Скорее всего как-то так же должно работать и для более старых, но не проверял.

При сборке проекта для net core формируется только dll, которая содержит только управляемый код, необходимый для среды исполнения net core и не содержит ни каких, специфичных для конечной платформы, заголовков и/или неуправляемых фрагментов кода. Это нужно для кроссплатформенности, которая в настоящее время вполне успешно реализована в net core. Запускать такую DLL как самостоятельное приложение нужно с помощью самой среды исполнения, например, командой:

> netcore.exe <имя сборки>

Чтобы получить исполняемый модуль для конкретной платформы следует использовать механизм публикации (Publish в контекстном меню проекта). Настраиваете публикацию вашего консольного приложения в локальную папку, выбираете в качестве целевой платформы Windows нужной разрядности и публикуете. В результате будет выполнена сборка dll, плюс сформирован одноименный .exe с необходимыми заголовками для ОС.

Чтобы не требовать от пользователя установку конкретной версии среды исполнения .net core, нужно указать в параметрах публикации режим Self contained, при котором все необходимое для работы будет скопировано в папку публикации. Этих файлов будет достаточно для запуска вашего приложения без установки среды исполнения на машине пользователя, но в таком случае, передавать приложение пользователю лучше в виде архива, т.к. в состав публикации включается, уменьшенная до необходимого и достаточного состава, среда исполнения .net core.

[Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1027410/198316) есть еще немного подробностей про режимы публикации, ну и официальную документацию ни кто не отменял.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант, создать проект на NET Core 3 и после сборки появится 
исполняемый файл (ехе. для Windows).

Comment: а так это вопрос-дубликат.  постоянно задается на so

Comment: так отметь как дубликат